# How to embed edit user profile page in a panel

Tags: 6, panels, users

I am trying to embed the edit user profile page (ie what appears at the url domain.com/user/27/edit) into a panel. I have searched high and low on how to do this but I can't find any info on it. Is it possible to do this? There reason why I am asking is that I want to clean up the user's profile page so that it looks more professional and is easier to use.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need 1 context and 1 relationship to get the Form pane

Context: User => current user

Relationship:  User category edit form from user (default?)

and THEN you get the "Forms" category with "General form pane" under it